# Issue with Ember Binding Style Attributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, binding

I feel like I'm following the documentation but I must be doing something wrong. Would love your help.

In my template, I have:

```
<div style="{{backgroundImage}}">
```

In my component js file I have:

```
backgroundImage: Ember.computed('background-image', function() {
  var imageUrl = this.item.attributes.imageMain.url;
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe('background-image: url('+ imageUrl +')');
})
```

Things are working fine, but I'm still getting the warning in the console:

```
WARNING: Binding style attributes may introduce cross-site scripting vulnerabilities; please ensure that values being bound are properly escaped. For more information, including how to disable this warning, see http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes.
```

Would love any help / second eye. Thanks so much!!

Comment: there is no problem, it's just an advisory; reminding you to sanitize user input. CSS can be used to fool users

Comment: @dandavis I understand but I thought that's what I was doing with that, sanitizing the CSS. How do I remove the warning? Was looking at this: https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes.

Comment: you can avoid setting inline styles. Implementing a CSP might remove the warning.

Comment: try without quotes `<div style={{backgroundImage}}`. tell us about ur ember version

Comment: Its fixed 2.10.0

Comment: Hooorah!!! It was the quotes in the templates that did it! Thank you @kumkanillam

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kumkanillam. The quotes in the template were extra.

So now this is what the template looks like:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage}}>
```

Comment: This is [fixed now](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/112d7caed9e292c31750347a1b355cfde1ecb55a).